UserManager: GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync() Invalid Token
I have gone through most posts on this topic, none seem to help/work, so resorting to posting my own question...
Scenario: In my ASP.net App I have a setting where I allow the user to enable or disable user lockout - When Its Enabled, my process of Generating the Email Token and Confirming using the URL works, but when the User Lockout is disabled, it doesnt work and I get an invalid token error when confirming:

Here is the code Im using to Encode and Decode when confirming:
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
                string viewName = await GenerateEmailToken(user);
                return View(viewName);
}

...
private async Task<string> GenerateEmailToken(IdentityUser user)
{
    string redirectView = "DisplayEmail";
    try
    {
        var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userid = user.Id, code = code }, Request.Url.Scheme);

  ...(Other Code here)

...
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    if (await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(userId))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    IdentityResult result;
    try
    {
        result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return View();
    }

    var invlidToken = result.Errors.Any(x => x.Contains("Invalid token."));
    if (invlidToken)
    {
        ViewBag.errorMessage = "Email Confirmation failed. Confirmation token invalid or expired.".Translate();
        string resendUrl = Url.Action("ResendToken", "Account", new { userRef = DataProtector.Encrypt(userId) }, Request.Url.Scheme);
        ViewBag.AdditionalMessage = $"<a href=\"{ resendUrl }\">" + "Click here".Translate()+"</a> "+"to resend the token.".Translate();
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.errorMessage = "Email Confirmation failed. Please contact support.".Translate();
    }
    return View("Error");

}

I have compared the Encoded and Decoded tokens when adding to the Email URL as well as when it is returned and decoded and they are exactly the same....Why on earth would it still be seen as invalid ?
Any idea why this would happen ?

Hi @AxleWack, can you share the code instead of screenshot?

Hey @Rena I have replaced the screenshots with the bits of code. Thanks!
